# Split using sed

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have to split

```
[X] ||| you owns the [X,1] ||| you own the [X,1] ||| 1 0.02020 0.07847 0.36788 3 -0.00000 -0.00000
```

at the pipes and output those line whose 2nd and 3rd argument are different.

Comment: A quick start: `sed -n '/^[^|]\+|||\(.\+\?|||\)\1/p'`, `grep '^[^|]\+|||\(.\+\?|||\)\1'` or `awk -F'\\|\\|\\|' '$2==$3'`. (Anybody is free to expand it into an answer.)

Answer (score 3):

Some explanations of the @manatwork comment/answer:

- `grep` version: `grep '^[^|]\+|||\(.\+\?|||\)\1'`

  - `^`: match the beginning of the line
  - `[^|]`: match any character excepted `|`
  - `\+`: match one or more time the preceding pattern
  - `|||`: match your separator
  - `\(` and `\)`: save the value matched between parenthesis in `\1`
  - `.`: match any character
  - `\+\?`: one or more time, but non greedy
  - `|||`: match your separator again
  - `\1`: match the previously text seen between parenthesis

  The idea here is to skip the beginning of the line until the first separator, then to save the value found until the end of second separator, and then match only line having exactly the same value as `\1` after the second operator (meaning the 3rd field)
- `sed` version: `sed -n '/^[^|]\+|||\(.\+\?|||\)\1/p'`

  Same meaning as `grep`, with an additional `/` at begin and end of line to indicate the pattern, plus an extra command character `p` at the end to print matching lines.
- `awk` version: `awk -F'\\|\\|\\|' '$2==$3'`

  - `-F'\\|\\|\\|'`: indicate the field separator: `|||` escaped in this case
  - `'$2==$3'`: filter input only where second and third field are equals

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the `awk` solution, but if you want to use Bash only, here is my answer:

```
foo() 
{ 
    local filename="$1";
    [[ $filename ]] || return 1

    while read -r line; do
        l="${line#*|||}"; a2="${l%%|||*}"
        l="${l#*|||}"; a3="${l%%|||*}"
        [[ $a2 = $a3 ]] && echo "$line"
    done < "$filename"
}
```

**Usage:** `foo filename.txt`

**Sample output:**

```
rany$ cat > filename.txt
a|||b|||c|||d|||
a|||b|||c|||d|||
a|||E|||E|||d|||
a|||B|||B|||d|||

rany$ foo filename.txt
a|||E|||E|||d|||
a|||B|||B|||d|||
```